Is the extension mod irreducible polynomial Galois?
Given a field $\mathbb{K}$ and an irreducible polynomial
$p(x) \in \mathbb{K}[x]$, one can construct always a field
in which $p(x)$ has a root, in particular $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$
(the quotient field). Are there specific conditions under which $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$
is a Galois extension of $K$?
For context an exercise with specific choices for $\mathbb{K}$ and (p(x)) lead me to this general question.
Let me add some thoughs, why I find it quite confusing.
According to Theorem 13.6 from Dummit & Foot actually any extension created by
adjoining a root of $p(x)$ to $\mathbb{K}$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$,
so can I pick a specific root (call it $\alpha$) and check if $\mathbb{K}(\alpha)$
is a Galois extension and if so would that imply this to be the case
for all the other choices?
Moreover does $\mathbb{K}(\alpha)$ introduce really just one root? Because Theorem 13.4 states that $\mathbb{K}(\alpha)$ contains
$\alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}$, where $n$ is the degree of $p$ and any of their linear combinations. If those would also be roots of
$p(x)$ then the Galois group fixing $\mathbb{K}$ would contain much more potential homomorphisms to check.
If this is wrong, (so the Galois Group consists only of the trivial $\{id\}$), then
examples such as $p(x) = (x - \alpha)^n$ seem paradoxical to me, since on one hand their degree is $n$ and by the characterization (3) before Theorem 14 ($n = |Aut(K/F)|$),
the extension would not be Galois (or trivially $\alpha$ is a root of an inseparable polynomial), and on the other $p(x)$ seems to factor completely
into linear factors over $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$ namely the constant factor 0, which would make it a splitting field (although it feels like an abuse of the definition for a splitting field here).

Note that the splitting field of a polynomial is not necessary a Galois extension. It is necessary a normal extension, but might not be Galois. For a finite extension to be Galois, it has to be the splitting field of a separable polynomial. So there is no contradiction here.

In general, $K(\alpha)$ of course can contain more roots than just $\alpha$. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ contains all the roots of $x^2-2$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ contains only one root of $x^3-2$.

Thanks @Mark, I had falsely assumed every splitting field is Galois. I've seen
the examples before but was not sure until know, that they were describing the
situation from my questions. Can you share your insight in regard to a potential
equivalence between one adjoined root being Galois and the others? Or do I have to
check if $\mathbb{K}(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ (all roots adjoined) is Galois? With the final goal to show that $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$ is too.

If $K(\alpha)$ is Galois over $K$, and if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same minimal polynomial over $K$, then $K(\beta)=K(\alpha)$, and a fortiori $K(\beta)$ is Galois over $K$.

Thanks to the comments from @Gerry Myerson and @Mark I believe to have the solution to the exercise and on the way collected the answers to my question too.

Does picking one root and verifying that its extension is Galois implies the same for all the others.


Yes, since $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x)) \simeq \mathbb{K}(\alpha) \simeq \mathbb{K}(\beta)$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are distinct roots of the polynomial  $p(x)$.


Does $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$ introduce just one root or all of the roots of the polynomial to $\mathbb{K}$?


It does not introduce all roots except when one root can generate all the others. An example for this situation is $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}$ and $p(x) = x^n - 1$, then $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x)) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\omega_n)$, where $\omega$ is the $n$-th root of unity. As all roots are of the shape $\omega_n^k$ for $k < n$ and $\omega_n^n = 1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ the extension is indeed Galois. As a counterexample the quotient of $\mathbb{K}[x] = \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $p(x) = x^p - 2$, $p$ prime, is not Galois with respect to $\mathbb{Q}$, since the polynomial requires both roots $\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega_p$ to split into linear factors (but only one is adjoined by the extension).


Is the quotient of $p(x) = (x - \alpha)^n$ for a certain field $\mathbb{K}$ a Galois extension?


Yes, if $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$ then the trivial extension $\mathbb{K}$ is Galois, as $\alpha$ is also a root of $x - \alpha$, which is separable. Otherwise if $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{K}$ then it is not separable, hence any extension with $\alpha$ not Galois. In any case just being the splitting field of $p(x)$ is not enough, $p(x)$ or at least the minimal polynomials for all elements that the extension adjoins need to be separable too.


For $\mathbb{K}[x]/(p(x))$ to be Galois, you need it to be separable, which is equivalent to $p'\neq 0$, and to be normal, which means the splitting field of $p$ over $\mathbb{K}$ has degree $\deg p$.
But I don't think you can very easily determine that. This was also asked here.
